# An equality involving the lower Gamma incomplete function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to prove the following equality:
 $$
 \gamma(r,x)=\int_0^x  \Gamma(r,y)   \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-(x-y) } (x-y) ^{mr-1}}{\Gamma(mr)}dy,
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function,  $\gamma(\cdot, \cdot)$ the lower incomplete Gamma function and $\Gamma(\cdot, \cdot)$ the upper incomplete Gamma function:
$$
\Gamma(r) = \int_0^{+\infty} t^{r-1}e^{-t}\ dt, \quad  \Gamma(r,x) = \int_x^{+\infty} t^{r-1}e^{-t}\ dt, \quad \gamma(r,x) = \int_0^{x} t^{r-1}e^{-t}\ dt,
$$
and $x>0, r>0.$

I tried to use Mathematica and it was not successful. I coded it numerically and did not find any counter example, so it seems to be true. Help would be gratefully acknowledged!